NEXTAUTH-redirection problem after successful authentication with NextAuth
I am developing a next.js application, I use nextauth to manage the connection. I coded my api and my sql database.
When I connect and the credentials are correct, I have my API that interacts with my mysql database and returns a status 200 to indicate that the credentials are good but I do not have a redirection to my main page. Modifying the url directly does not seem to work either
here is my options.ts file in /app/api/auth/[...nextauth] :
import type { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth'; // Import the 'Profile' type from 'next-auth'
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import axios from 'axios';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import ChangePasswordDialog from '@/components/changePasswordDialog';


export const options: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,

    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {},
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const { email, password } = credentials as { email: string, password: string };
        console.log('Credentials  :', credentials );
        try {
          const { data: users } = await axios.get(process.env.API_URL + 'utilisateurs/EmailsAndPasswords');
          if (credentials) {
            const user = users.find((user: any) => user.email === email);
            if (user) {
              const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password_hash);
              console.log(user);
              
              if (isMatch) {
                return user;
                
              } else {
                return null;
              }
            } else {
              return null;
            }
          }
          console.log('Aucun credential fourni');
          return null;
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Erreur lors de l\'authentification:', error);
          return null;
        }
      }
    })
  ],

  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt', // Utiliser JWT pour gérer les sessions
    maxAge: 30 * 60, // Durée de vie du token
  },

  jwt: {
    secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET as string,
  },
  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET as string,


  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account, profile }) {
      if (account && account.provider === 'google') {
        if (!profile?.email) {
          throw new Error('No email returned from Google');
        }
        const emailDomain = '@epfprojets.com';
        if (profile.email.endsWith(emailDomain)) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
      return true;
    },
    
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.id;
        token.email = user.email;
        token.name = user.name;
      }
      return token;
    },

    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.user = {
        email: token.email as string,
        name: token.name as string,
      };
      return session;
      
    },

    async redirect({ url, baseUrl }: { url: string; baseUrl: string; }) {
      return url.startsWith(baseUrl) ? url : baseUrl;
    }

  },
  
};

and here is the login page I created in /app/api/auth
"use client"

import Link from "next/link"
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react"
import {useSession} from "next-auth/react"
import { useState } from "react"
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation"
import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react';


import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button"
import {
    Card,
    CardContent,
    CardDescription,
    CardHeader,
    CardTitle,
} from "@/components/ui/card"
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input"
import { Label } from "@/components/ui/label"
import { Separator } from "@/components/ui/separator"

export default function LoginForm() {

    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [error, setError] = useState('');

    const router = useRouter();

    const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const res = await signIn('credentials', {
                email,
                password,
                redirect: false
            });
            if (res && res.error) {
                setError("Email ou mot de passe incorrect");
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        };
    }

    return (
        <Card className="mx-auto max-w-sm">
            <CardHeader>
                <CardTitle className="text-2xl">Login</CardTitle>
                <CardDescription>
                    Enter your email below to login to your account
                </CardDescription>
            </CardHeader>
            <CardContent>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <div className="grid gap-4">
                        <div className="grid gap-2">
                            <Label htmlFor="email">Email</Label>
                            <Input
                                id="email"
                                type="email"
                                placeholder="m@example.com"
                                required
                                value={email}
                                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="grid gap-2">
                            <div className="flex items-center">
                                <Label htmlFor="password">Password</Label>
                                <Link href="#" className="ml-auto inline-block text-sm underline">
                                    Forgot your password?
                                </Link>
                            </div>
                            <Input id="password" type="password" required value={password}
                                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                                placeholder="By Quentin Dufour" />
                        </div>
                        {error && (
                            <div className="m-auto">
                                <Label htmlFor="error" className="bg-red-500 text-white w-fit text-sm py-1 px-3 rounded-md mt-2">
                                    {error}
                                </Label>
                            </div>
                        )}
                        <Button type="submit" className="w-full">
                            Login
                        </Button>
                        <Separator className="h-[2px]"/>
                        <Button variant="outline" className="w-full">
                            Login with Google
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </CardContent>
        </Card>
    )
}

Here is my middleware.js:
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";

I have several avenues that I am looking into without much conviction:

the lines :

jwt: {
  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET as string,
},
secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET as string,

seem to be a source of the problem. When I comment out these lines, I can manually redirect to my main page by modifying the url after successful authentication.

a redirect in the: callback{} in options.ts? (already tried without success for the moment)
a router.replace() in my login page? (already tried without success for the moment)
setting up ?

Thank you for any help you can give me and for the time you will devote to my problem.

Redirect manually instead
import { useSearchParams, useRouter } from "next/navigation"

import { Route } from "@/routers/types"

export default function LoginForm() {
    const router = useRouter()
    const searchParams = useSearchParams()

    const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {

        const callbackUrl = searchParams.get("callbackUrl")
        signIn("credentials", {
            email,
            password,
            redirect: false
        })
            .then((res: SignInResponse | undefined) => {
                if (!res.ok)
                    alert("Something went wrong")
                else {
                    if (callbackUrl)
                        router.push(callbackUrl as Route)
                    else
                        router.push("/home")
                }
            })
    }
}

